# Plot points into a boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I tried to use these commands to plot a boxplot with their corresponding points in the same column of each box. For the moment, I just can plot the points with no order. How can I plot rnorm1 in the same column of the boxplot Ant1?

Function 'boxplot' would be mandatory.

```
rnorm1 = rnorm(100)
rnorm2 = rnorm(100)

boxplot(rnorm1, rnorm2, names=c("Ant1", "Ant2"), col=c("green", "red"))
points(rnorm1, rnorm2)
```

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `points(rbind(cbind(1, rnorm1), cbind(2, rnorm2)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to recommend the `beeswarm` package:

```
library(beeswarm)
df <- cbind.data.frame(rnorm1, rnorm2)
boxplot(df)
beeswarm(df, add=T)
```

[image]

Or try `dplyr` and `ggplot2` within the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

cbind.data.frame(rnorm1, rnorm2) %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key, value)) +
   geom_boxplot() + 
   geom_beeswarm() + 
   theme_bw()
```

[image]